# How to check if word is not in list

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am using praw to scrape a subbreddit "RocketLeagueExchange"

I want to check if the reddit title has any of the ignorewords. If not, append the list with its title and url.
When removing the part about checking if any of the ignorewords are in the title it works.

Id also like to put

```py
if not any(ignorewords in submission.title.lower for ignorewords in submission.title.lower):
```

but I get an error when using `.lower`

```
File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    if not any(ignorewords in submission.title.lower for ignorewords in submission.title.lower):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

What I tried:

```py
platform = "Xbox"
item = "tw zomba"

ignorewords= ["pricecheck","price check","discussion","giveaway","store"]
reddittrades = []
for submission in reddit.subreddit("RocketLeagueExchange").search("{} {}".format(platform, item), limit=10):
  if not any(ignorewords in submission.title for ignorewords in submission.title):
    reddittrades.append(submission.title + submission.url) 
   
    
print(reddittrades)
```

I get `[]` as the output - when there are clearly many results on reddit

Comment: Use `.lower()` instead of `.lower`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is the following:

```py
platform = "Xbox"
item = "tw zomba"

ignorewords= ["pricecheck","price check","discussion","giveaway","store"]
reddittrades = []
for submission in reddit.subreddit("RocketLeagueExchange").search("{} {}".format(platform, item), limit=10):
  if not any([word.lower() in ignorewords for word in submission.title]):
    reddittrades.append(submission.title + submission.url) 
   
    
print(reddittrades)
```

Comment: ty for the answer im still getting results with pricecheck